# Calculate difference between two dates in the same MS Access table

Tags: datediff, calculation, ms-access-2016

I'm working on a database where the production team can input their worked hours and such into a form. I want to have them fill in when they started and completed a task and calculate the difference and input that into a table.

I've tried using simple subtractions in calculated fields, `DateDiff`-queries, and field expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your fields are named `Start` and `End`, add the following field in the query, this will give you the summary in decimal hours.

```vb
FormatNumber(DateDiff("n", [Start], Nz([End], [Start])) / 60)
```

Comment: I might be putting it in wrong but just copy pasting this into a query field gives me an error. It's in Dutch so I'll give a rough translation. "there is a missing operand or operator, you submitted an invalid comma or you didn't place the text in the expression in quotation marks"

Comment: nevermind! thank you for your solition. I just had to change the comma's to ; for it to work for me. it works great!

Comment: You need to first add the name of the field it will receive, like this:
    `My Fielde: FormatNumber(DateDiff("n", [Start], Nz([End], [Start])) / 60)`

Comment: yeah, I did that. The problem was that for some reason the program required me to use ; instead of ,